# avoid renaming of graphical objects

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, user-interface

I'm trying to modify components of a GUI in C#, my IDE is Visual Studio 2010. 
I noticed that whenever I try to use the visual interface to move around graphical components, all my components get renamed. For instance, `myLabel` is renamed `label1`, `mySeries` becomes `series1` and so on.

Can I keep the original variable names I assign in the code and still be able to arrange objects visually?

**EDIT**: For instance, I just changed the position of a label, and in the code all `ChartAreas`, `Series` and `Labels` (from `DataVisualization.Charting`) get renamed.

Comment: are you renaming them from code or from designer properties windows?

Comment: In my code. I am working on somebody else's code and I am totally new to visual studio. :)

Comment: you should select the item in visual editor, then change it properties via properties window, I think you are using a 3rd party library for user interface, am I right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get why I should change any properties at all. :) I am using `Systems.Windows.Forms`. I believe it's the built-in library.

Comment: for example, select a button in your designer, right click and select properties, set name property from this window, for example `button_DoMagic`

Comment: By 'moving' you mean cut and paste into another Form? Simply moving will not change a name.

Comment: By moving I mean just modifying its position and/or size on the GUI. No cut and paste.

Comment: are you editing the designer.cs file directly? designer.cs is automatically generated by the editor. If you make changes in there, they could be overwritten when you save the project.

Comment: Yes, that's the file I am editing. Should I move the code somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use the visual interface **to set the name** of your controls ? (via the property window).

You should not mix auto-generated and manually-generated code. That it.
If you want to use the designer, you should not take the habit of editing the generated code ("*.Designer.cs" files).

If you want to port your manually generated code to the designer you will have a bad time.

Anyway : if you use the designer to set the name of your control, it should not change when you move them.

Comment: Oh but I don't want any renaming. The names I assigned are the ones I would really like to keep. I just would like to move graphical components visually. Is this possible?

Comment: You should not mix manually and automatically generated code. I think your issue come from the "myControl.Name" property, it have to be set to the control name (here "myControl"), otherwise, the designer will rename the control.

Comment: If you use the designer to set the name of your control, it will auto-generate all code to 'definitely' set the name.

Comment: Do you mean that for any given component, the `Name` property should reflect the name of component itself? For example `someLabel.Name = "someLabel"`?

Comment: I tested it, removing the ".Name" property in the generated code do not cause the control to be renamed to a default name. Anyway, the ".Name" property is indeed set as you described by the visual designer.

Comment: I just saw that all ChartAreas, Series and Legends (from `DataVisualization.Charting`) get renamed as soon as change the position of a label.